# Question regarding to the converse of a basic continuity theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was wondering if this statement is correct or not. (I feel like it is not, but can someone give me a counterexample to it?)

$f$ is continous and $f(x_n)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow f(x)\implies x_n \stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow x$.

Answer (score 3):

Not correct as is. Take e.g. $f(x)=0$ all $x.$ Then any sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$ but that doesn't force $x_n$ to converge to $x.$

Comment: Or for a less trivial example, if $f(x) = \sin x$, we could have a sequence where $f(x_n)$ converges to 0 because $x_n$ values get arbitrarily close to the function zeros $n\pi$, but if they keep switching between different $n\pi$ values, $x_n$ has no limit. I think we'll need at least that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Yes @aschepler I was also thinking injectivity would be needed, and may even be enough to rule out counterexamples.